# Where is 'javac' in java-17-openjdk-amd64?

Tags: java, ubuntu, javac, wsl-2

**Win10 WSL 2 over an Ubuntu layer**

**Ubuntu:** lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal\

**Java:** java --version
openjdk 17.0.1 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, Sharing)

I've successfully installed openjdk 17.0.1, but there is no 'javac' command in bin (such as exists in ***java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin***). There is no javac counterpart in ***java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin***.

I've googled, oogled, and bugled to no great gain. In my experience, this means I'm missing something simple.

Someone please guide me here. What gives? How can I get the 'javac' command in openjdk 17.0.1, or how do I use that SDK to create a class?

Comment: WSL makes no difference _whatsoever_ -- it's downloading the same package used by any other Ubuntu. The important question is _exactly_ which jdk package you installed. Use `dpkg -l` to show that, not `java --version`. (If it's not shown in `dpkg`, that tells us you didn't install it the Ubuntu way, which gives us a place to start on tracking down the problem)

Comment: ...mind, since you solved the problem by uninstalling/reinstalling, it's probably no longer possible to figure out how the problem was generated in the first place, and thus impossible to edit a [mre] into the question to make its answer reproducible/testable/verifiable (and thus to allow the bounds of its applicability to be determined and documented). Under the circumstances, I would generally suggest deleting the question.

Comment: ...no `java-17-openjdk-amd64` is shown in https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/allpackages (the list of official packages for Ubuntu 20.04.3).

Comment: I am not sure, but unlike previous version, I am able to run a .java file directly with `java MyClass.java` without running a javac command before to create a .class file. (Directly running java MyClass.java is not generating a .class but straight away runs the program)

Answer (score 2):

RHEL/RockyLinux/CentOs/AlmaLinux etc: javac is in "devel" package

```
dnf -y install java-17-openjdk
dnf -y install java-17-openjdk-devel
```

Then set default versions

```
 alternatives --config java
 alternatives --config javac
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure which directions I used to install Open JDK before, but I followed the following instructions to remove and re-install: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-openjdk-17-on-ubuntu-20-04/

I now have 'javac' in java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin.

Whew.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/javac" 1
```